# MySQL Query, Count Number of Rows with Same Value Limited to 5 Results

Tags: php, mysql, count

Here's a sample table (ftm_data):

```
-----Entry Date----- | ---Area---
2017-05-05 17:41:55  |    PRQ
2017-05-05 17:38:05  |    PRQ
2017-05-05 17:35:45  |    MKT
2017-05-05 16:43:25  |    ZAM
2017-05-05 16:40:55  |    TSC
2017-05-05 16:36:12  |    MKT
2017-05-05 16:20:25  |    PRQ
2017-05-05 15:38:45  |    GSC
2017-05-05 14:05:32  |    ILO
2017-05-05 13:54:08  |    PRQ
        ~            |     ~
```

1. What I need is to produce a result from query which would count the number of rows with the same Area (eg. PRQ) and display it in descending order (both counts and date of entry), but limited to 5 results only.

   ```
   ---Area--- | ---Count---
      PRQ     |      4
      MKT     |      2
      ZAM     |      1
      TSC     |      1
      GSC     |      1
   ```

   Can this be achieved using the following command?

   ```
   SELECT Area, COUNT(Area) as Count FROM ftm_data GROUP BY Area DESC LIMIT 5;
   ```

Comment: You should only ask one question.

Comment: `SELECT Area, COUNT(Area) as Count FROM ftm_data GROUP BY Area order by Count DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: SELECT Area, COUNT(Area) as Count FROM ftm_data GROUP BY Area order by Count DESC LIMIT 5 
try this

Comment: Ok seems I just missed the ORDER BY part of the query, really appreaciate the explanation for the -3 downvotes :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Area, COUNT(Area) as Count FROM ftm_data GROUP BY Area order by Count DESC LIMIT 5
```